# ERROR [CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task / java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Linear functions must only have a non empty coefficient

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

after a successful SonarQube update from v5.1.2 to v5.3 (Oracle DB migration was successful, SonarQube runs and its GUI works fine), we're facing problems when projects are to be analyzed.

Project analysis itself is successful on the client side (tested with Maven and SonarRunner):

```
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 749ms, dir size=2 MB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 530ms, zip size=772 KB
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 156ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse <project-url-on-sonarqube>
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at https://<server-url>/api/ce/task?id=AVKcv7V9xPfxTGjoPPPN
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but the project's GUI on SonarQube (Project / Admnistration / Background Tasks) reports an error:

```
2016.02.01 12:21:09 INFO  [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=<our-project:id> | id=AVKckJxVsuuY6y_oEQj3
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ExtractReportStep] Analysis report extracted | compressedSize=772 KB
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Extract report | time=78ms
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep] SonarQube plugins:
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - C / C++ / Objective-C 3.8.1 (cpp)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - CSS 1.5 (css)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Python 1.5 (python)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - PMD 2.5 (pmd)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - StyleCop 1.1 (stylecop)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Android 1.1 (android)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - JSON 1.2 (JSON)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Motion Chart 1.7 (motionchart)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio Projects 1.2 (visualstudio)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - JavaScript 2.9 (javascript)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Java Properties 1.5 (javaProperties)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - C# 4.3 (csharp)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Findbugs 3.3 (findbugs)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Java 3.9 (java)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - LDAP 1.5.1 (ldap)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - SQALE 2.7 (sqale)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Web 2.4 (web)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - XML 1.3 (xml)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Pitest 0.6 (pitest)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Checkstyle 2.4 (checkstyle)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - Views 2.10 (views)
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep] Settings for module: <our-project:id>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.branding.logo.location=MENU
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.buildbreaker.skip=true
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.id=20160201121821
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.projectsdashboard.columns=METRIC.ncloc;METRIC.sqale_rating;METRIC.blocker_violations;METRIC.critical_violations;METRIC.major_violations;METRIC.minor_violations;BUILD_TIME.build_time;METRIC.weighted_violations;
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.projectsdashboard.defaultSortedColumn=project
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.projectsdashboard.showTreemap=false
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.serverBaseURL=https://<our-sonar-server-url>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.startTime=2016-02-01T12:18:21+0100
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.treemap.colormetric=violations_density
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.treemap.sizemetric=lines
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.core.version=5.3
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.cpd.cross_project=true
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.cpp.license.secured=******
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.cpp.licenseHash.secured=******
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.cxx.suffixes.headers=.h,.hh,.hpp,.hxx,.h++
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.cxx.suffixes.sources=.cc,.cpp,.cxx,.c++,.ipp,.c
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.defaultGroup=sonar-users
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.dryRun.cache.lastUpdate=1437048657799
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.events.category.Rules=Changes and Updates of the Rule Set
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.findbugs.timeout=2400000
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.forceAnalysis=true
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.forceAuthentication=true
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.host.url=http://<our-sonar-server-url>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.issue.ignore.block=141586926707101
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.issue.ignore.block.141586926707101.beginBlockRegexp=// @UKA_GENERATION_START@
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.issue.ignore.block.141586926707101.endBlockRegexp=// @UKA_GENERATION_END@
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.links.ci=
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.links.homepage=
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.links.issue=
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.links.scm=
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.links.scm_dev=
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.login=sonar.builder
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.maven.projectDependencies=[]
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.moduleKey=<our-project:id>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.mojoUseRunner=true
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.motionchart.defaultmetrics=violations_density,lines,function_complexity,complexity
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.organisation=<our-organisation-name>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.password=******
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.pdf.password=******
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.pdf.skip=true
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.pdf.username=<user-name>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.permission.template.TRK.default=default_template_for_projects
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.permission.template.VW.default=default_template_for_views
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.permission.template.default=default_template_for_projects
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.pitest.mode=reuseReport
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectBaseDir=c:\data\development\PlugAndPlay\eclipse\Tools
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectBuildDir=c:\data\development\PlugAndPlay\eclipse\Tools\target
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectDescription=<project-description
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectKey=<our-project:id>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectName=<project-name>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.projectVersion=1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.purge.minimumPeriodInHours=24
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.scm.enabled=false
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.server_id=<server-id>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.server_id.ip_address=<ip-address>
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.skipPackageDesign=true
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.sourceEncoding=windows-1252
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.sources=c:\data\development\PlugAndPlay\eclipse\Tools\pom.xml,c:\data\development\PlugAndPlay\eclipse\Tools\src
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.sqale.licenseHash.secured=******
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.timemachine.period2=14
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.timemachine.period3=30
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.vbnet.license.secured=******
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.views.license.secured=******
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.views.licenseHash.secured=******
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.visualstudio.enable=true
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.LogScannerContextStep]   - sonar.working.directory=c:\data\development\PlugAndPlay\eclipse\Tools\target\sonar
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Log scanner context | time=4ms
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load analysis metadata | time=0ms
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Build tree of components | time=21ms
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Validate project | time=3ms
2016.02.01 12:21:10 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load debt model | time=14ms
2016.02.01 12:21:11 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVKckJxVsuuY6y_oEQj3
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Linear functions must only have a non empty coefficient
    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:125) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.server.debt.internal.DefaultDebtRemediationFunction.validate(DefaultDebtRemediationFunction.java:82) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.api.server.debt.internal.DefaultDebtRemediationFunction.<init>(DefaultDebtRemediationFunction.java:45) ~[sonar-plugin-api-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleImpl.effectiveRemediationFunction(RuleImpl.java:124) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleImpl.<init>(RuleImpl.java:53) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleRepositoryImpl.loadRulesFromDb(RuleRepositoryImpl.java:102) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleRepositoryImpl.ensureInitialized(RuleRepositoryImpl.java:91) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.RuleRepositoryImpl.findByKey(RuleRepositoryImpl.java:62) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.LoadQualityProfilesStep$IsValid.apply(LoadQualityProfilesStep.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.LoadQualityProfilesStep$IsValid.apply(LoadQualityProfilesStep.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$7.computeNext(Iterators.java:647) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:268) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.copyOf(ImmutableList.java:226) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.toList(FluentIterable.java:334) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.LoadQualityProfilesStep.execute(LoadQualityProfilesStep.java:63) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:39) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:72) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
2016.02.01 12:21:11 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=<our-project:id> | id=AVKckJxVsuuY6y_oEQj3 | time=1957ms
```

Do you have an idea what causes the described problem?

Our SonarQube uses:

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Oracle JDBC driver, Driver Version 11.2.0.4.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You very likely have a rule which defines a LINEAR remediation function for which both coefficient and offset are defined. Only the former must be defined.

Unfortunately, the error does not show which rule is incorrectly configured (improvement ticket [SONAR-7264](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7264) created).

Since you have the Sqale plugin installed, the debt of a rule might have been improperly override.

Other probable cause is an old version of a language plugin which might have had an improperly configured rule for a while but for which, in 5.3, SQ now throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

It did the job.
After resetting in 'Administration' > 'Configuration' > 'SQALE' > 'Back Up / Restore', 'Reset Models', button 'Reset', projects could be analyzed properly.
Thanks a lot.